# replace span class with other span class

Tags: google-chrome

It's kind of hard to explain. basically I want to change the span text in a class to the span text of another text in a chrome extension. The website code looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNJoO.png)

I want to change that 6 to the text of the other class that the 8 is in. I don't really know java that well so can someone please help.

EDIT:
I figured out how to change only that class but i still don't know how to get the text of the other class and change it to that. I was trying this:
    document.getElementsByClassName('points').innerHTML
but it returned undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getElementsByClassName()` function doesn't return just one item:

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

**Source:** [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

I'm not too sure what your requirement is as the question is rather ambiguous. My assumption is that you would like the score and points to match for each `score-wrapper` section, like so:

```
var scoreWrappers = document.getElementsByClassName('score-wrapper');

[].forEach.call(scoreWrappers, function (scoreWrapper) {
    var score = scoreWrapper.getElementsByClassName('score')[0];
    var points = scoreWrapper.getElementsByClassName('points')[0];

    score.innerText = points.innerText;
});
```